# Text editor that doesn't change line endings on paste

Tags: windows, text-editor

All text editors I've tried so far, including Notepad++, Sublime Text, SciTE, VS Code and others, adjust line endings on paste to match the current document settings. For example, if I copy this to clipboard:

```
line1 [LF] line2
```

and the document in the editor is set to CRLF, this is what I'll get after the paste:

```
line1 [CRLF] line2
```

I don't want that. I want the original line endings preserved. Is there an editor (for Windows) that can do that, or can be configured to do that?

It can be paid (though preferably free).

Comment: Are you saying that you want to have a file with mixed line endings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can do `Paste Binary Content` (found under `Edit -> Paste Special`). This pastes EOL characters unchanged for me.

You can shortcut it using the `Shortcut mapper`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the accepted answer is to use the LuaScript plugin (install it via the plugin manager), then go to *Plugins > LuaScript > Edit Startup File* and paste this:

```
editor1.PasteConvertEndings = false
editor2.PasteConvertEndings = false
```

This will permamently keep the line endings (probably not recommended but if anybody wanted that..).